# How can I refresh a radSchedule after changes to a bound Dataset?

Tags: c#, dataset, telerik, radscheduler

I'm having some trouble with, I think, the radSchedular.

I have a radSchedular which I bind to a dataset.

I expected the radSchedular to update when I changed the dataset.  But I don't get this.

My question is.  How do I update the display of a radSchedular when the Dataset updates?

Example code:

How I bind:-

```
        private void BindToDataSet()
    {                

        //Map fields for Appointments
        AppointmentMappingInfo appointmentMappingInfo = new AppointmentMappingInfo();

        appointmentMappingInfo.Start = "appointments_Start";
        appointmentMappingInfo.End = "appointments_End";      //LOTS OF THESE SO I CUT THE REST OUT OF THIS EXAMPLE


        datasource.EventProvider.Mapping = appointmentMappingInfo;
        datasource.EventProvider.DataSource = dsSchedule.Tables[0];   //MY DATASET IS GENERATED FROM AN XML FILE WITH A SCHEMA

        //Bind
        radScheduler1.DataSource = datasource;
    }
```

How I get the dataset changed events:-

```
private void BindEvents(){
// RowChanged event handler.
dsSchedule.Tables[0].RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(RowChanged);

// Add a RowDeleted event handler.
dsSchedule.Tables[0].RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(RowDeleted);}
```

Event method:-

```
private void RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e){
StoreToXML();
BindEvents();}
```

How I store the data and, I thought, refresh the radSchedular:-

```
private void StoreToXML(){

//remove the dataset change deligates as we are about to change the Dataset and we don't want a loop
UnBindEvents();

foreach (DataRow rowAppointments in dsSchedule.Tables["Appointments"].Rows)
{
    string currentResource = rowAppointments["appointments_ResourceID"].ToString();

    foreach (DataRow rowResources in dsSchedule.Tables["Resources"].Rows)
    {
    if (rowResources["resources_ID"].ToString() == currentResource)
    {
        rowAppointments["appointments_Location"] = rowResources["resources_Name"];  //THIS IS WHY I WANT THE radSCHEDULAR TO UPDATE. 
    }                                       //I WANT TO SEE THE RESOURCE IN THE LOCATION FIELD
    }
}


StreamWriter myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"E:\My .NET\Hardware_Scheduler_Application\stdData.xml");
dsSchedule.WriteXml(myStreamWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
myStreamWriter.Close();
BindToDataSet();   //I THOUGHT THAT THIS WOULD REFRESH THE radSCHEDULAR

//rebind the changed events
BindEvents()}
```

Comment: Does the data set expose IObservable?

Comment: No I don't think DataSets do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue for myself by placing these two lines of code below at the end of the events `RadScheduler1_AppointmentInsert` and `RadScheduler1_AppointmentDelete` . The two lines are:

```
Appointments.Clear();
InitializeAppointments();
```

This will only work for you if you set your grid up by following the example given on the Telerik site. You can find a link here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx